# Trouble setting a length

Tags: errors, lengths, preamble

I'm starting with LaTeX, and there are things that puzzle me. I'm trying to set a length that's the `\textwidth` minus (let's say for example) two inches. In the preamble, I wrote:

```
\newlength{\bplen}
\setlength{\bplen}{\textwidth}
\addtolength{\pblen}{-2in}
```

The compiler tells me:

```
! Undefined control sequence. <argument> \pblen 
l.21 \addtolength{\pblen}{-2in}
! You can't use `blank space  ' after \advance.
\addtolength #1#2-<\advance #1 
                               #2\relax
l.21 \addtolength{\pblen}{-2in}
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
```

I've just *defined* `\bplen` and what's that about a missing `\begin{document}`? Aren't I allowed to set lengths in the preamble?

Comment: Is `pblen` a typo you made in the document?

Comment: @Seamus: I'm not sure how to handle question like this one, but you were faster and should have gotten the upvote reputation.

Comment: I feel shame. I do. Sorry.

Comment: @lockstep Don't worry about it. Your answer included the useful `\the` trick which I'd forgotten about, so that's value added. But I am going to spend the next week trawling through all your posts on this site and downvoting every single one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could it be simply a typo? Your first and your second code line contain `\bplen`, but your third `\pblen`.

EDIT: Without the typo your code works as intended:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength{\bplen}
\setlength{\bplen}{\textwidth}
\addtolength{\bplen}{-2in}

\begin{document}

Value of textwidth: \the\textwidth

Value of bplen: \the\bplen

\end{document}
```

Comment: I proofread it for typos maybe ten times! This is VERY embarrassing. Being new to LaTeX, I thought I'd done something wrong...

Comment: Actually, I did not know about the \the command. This is VERY useful. Thanks.

Comment: @eje211 typos are unavoidable. I spent some time today raging that LaTeX kept telling me that the `vebratim` environment doesn't exist...